How to show that $\{U_{n,i} \cap V_{n,i}\}_{i,n \geq 1}$ is a countable base for the topology on $\mathcal G\ $?
Let $\mathcal G$ be a topological groupoid i.e. $\mathcal G$ is a non-empty set endowed with a locally compact Hausdorff, second countable topology together with a distinguished subset $\mathcal G^{(2)} \subseteq \mathcal G \times \mathcal G$, a multiplication map $m : \mathcal G^{(2)} \longrightarrow \mathcal G$ defined by $(\alpha, \beta) \mapsto \alpha \beta$ and an inverse map $\iota : \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G$ defined by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^{-1}$ such that the following conditions are satisfied $:$

$(1)$ $(\alpha^{-1})^{-1} = \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal G$ i.e. $\iota$ is an involution.
$(2)$ If $(\alpha, \beta)$ and $(\beta, \gamma) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}$ then $(\alpha, \beta \gamma) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}$ and $(\alpha \beta, \gamma) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}.$ Moreover, the multiplication is associative i.e. $\alpha (\beta \gamma) = (\alpha \beta) \gamma.$
$(3)$ $(\gamma, \gamma^{-1}) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}$ for all $\gamma \in \mathcal G$ and for all $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathcal G^{(2)},$ we have $(\alpha \beta) \beta^{-1} = \alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1} (\alpha \beta) = \beta.$
$(4)$ The multiplication map $m$ and the inverse map $\iota$ are continuous.

Define a set $\mathcal G^{(0)} : = \{\gamma \gamma^{-1}\ |\ \gamma \in \mathcal G \}.$ This set is called the unit space of $\mathcal G$ and the elements of this set are called units of $\mathcal G.$ Consider the maps $r : \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G^{(0)}$ defined by $\gamma \mapsto \gamma \gamma^{-1}$ and $s : \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G^{(0)}$ defined by $\gamma \mapsto \gamma^{-1} \gamma.$  If $\mathcal G$ is a topological groupoid, then both the maps $r$ and $s$ are continuous. The maps $r$ and $s$ are called the range and the source map respectively.

Definition $:$ A topological groupoid $\mathcal G$ is said to be étale if the range map $r$ (and, consequently the source map $s$) is a local homeomorphism.


Fact $:$ If $\mathcal G$ is an étale groupoid, then $\mathcal G^{(0)}$ is open in $\mathcal G.$


Definition $:$ A subset $B$ of an étale groupoid $\mathcal G$ is said to be a bisection if there exists an open subsets $U$ containing $B$ such that $r \lvert_{U} : U \longrightarrow r(U)$ and $s \lvert_{U} : U \longrightarrow s(U)$ are both homeomorphisms onto the open subsets of $\mathcal G^{(0)}.$


Lemma $:$ If $\mathcal G$ is an étale groupoid, then $\mathcal G$ has a countable base of open bisections.
Proof. Since $\mathcal G$ is second countable, it is separable. Let $\{\gamma_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a countable dense subset of $\mathcal G.$ For each $\gamma_n,$ we can get hold of countable neighbourhood bases $\{U_{n,i}\}_{i \geq 1}$ and $\{V_{n,i}\}_{i \geq 1}$ at $\gamma_n$ such that $r$ is a homeomorphism from each $U_{n,i}$ onto an open set and $s$ is a homeomorphism from each $V_{n,i}$ onto an open set. Then $\{U_{n,i} \cap V_{n,i}\ |\ i, n \geq 1\}$ is a countable base for $\mathcal G$ consisting of open bisections.

In the above proof there are two facts which are unclear to me $:$

$(1)$ Why do neighbourhood bases such as $\{U_{n,i}\}_{i \geq 1}$ and $\{V_{n,i}\}_{i \geq 1}$ at each $\gamma_n$ exist?
$(2)$ Why $\{U_{n,i} \cap V_{n,i}\ |\ i,n \geq 1 \}$ is a base for the topology on $\mathcal G\ $?

The questions might seem to be a bit stupid but I am having hard time understanding them. Any suggestion in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

The first question is really just topological, so it might help to abstract away from the groupoidal case. Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a local homeomorphism and that $X$ is first countable.  By first countability, any point $x$ of $X$ has a countable neighborhood basis $\{U'_{i}\}_{i \geq 1}$.  Since $f$ is a local homeomorphism, so is its restriction to $U'_{i}$ for any $i$.  It follows that for all $i \geq 1$ there is an open neighborhood $U_{i} \subseteq U'_{i}$ of $x$ such that $f : U_{i} \to f(U_{i})$ is a homeomorphism with $f(U_{i})$ open in $Y$.  So $\{U_{i}\}_{i \geq 1}$ is a countable neighborhood basis of $x$ such that $f$ is a homeomorphism from each $U_{i}$ onto an open set.  Taking $X$ to be $\mathcal{G}$, taking $f$ to be $s$ or $r$, and taking $x$ to be $\gamma_{n}$ gives an argument for (1).
For the second question, I actually don't see why $\{U_{n, i} \cap V_{n, i}\}_{i, n \geq 1}$ should be a base for the topology on $\mathcal{G}$.  And I have a mild suspicion that it's not true.  I think the proof of the Lemma that's really intended by your source would go like this:
Since $\mathcal{G}$ is second countable, it suffices to show that it has a base of open bisections.  For this it suffices to show that each point has a neighborhood basis of open bisections.  And this was shown in the topological argument above.

Since the $U$ and $V$ form neighborhood bases, don't we have that for every point $x$ and every neighborhood $N$ of $x$, there is a subset of $N$ of the form ${U_{n,i} \cap V_{n,i}}$ containing $x$? And that means every nonempty open set is a union of such sets, ie they form a base?

Maybe!  I don't see why, though.  Choose some $x$ in $\mathcal{G}$ that doesn't belong to the family ${\gamma_{n}}$.  For which $n$ and which $i$ does $x$ belong to $U_{n, i} \cap V_{n, i}$?

Ah yes, I see your point. I now share your suspicion that it's not true :)
